# static IP in Ubuntu server same but not connect with change router

Tags: networking, server, lubuntu, dhcp

I have a Ubuntu Server with a static IP(192.168.0.1), when going to change router then cannot connect server  with this IP(192.168.0.1), cannot ping this IP. but when i check server IP its still old static IP.

Comment: Are you saying that both the router and the server have the same IP of 192.168.0.1?  If that is the case, change the server to an unused IP in the 192.168.0.x range then access the router at 192.168.0.1.

Comment: No now its different now my server static ip 192.168.0.1 but its not same with router ip. so can i change router configuration ?

Comment: As long as your router IP is not 192.168.0.1.  But, it should be something from 192.168.0.2 - 254 to be in the same subnet to access it.

Comment: My router Ip address 192.168.1.1 but now my server static  ip 192.168.0.1, so where i will change and got connected in server.

Comment: You would have to change your server IP to something in the 192.168.1.x subnet to access the router at 192.168.1.1.  Or, change your server to DHCP for the time being until you change your router.

Comment: i have FTP/SVN against my old server static IP, if i change all those thing works or not ?

Comment: Unless you have another computer that you can hook up to your router in the same subnet, you will not be able to configure the router.  I don't know about the stuff you mentioned, but I have done tons with networking.  If I have to configure a router I sometimes will plug it into a laptop that I can configure it from as to not mess with my other systems.

Comment: is it possible without touch my old server static ip, can i configure or give new range on router for access my old server static ip.  if its possible i am able to change router setting. but its risky because i have FTP/SVN if i change server ip maybe its not work then

Comment: Please read: https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work

Comment: Thank  you for this link, but not understand so huge theory, can you tell me possible solution, change server ip or change router configuration, then if i change server ip then all FTP/SVN works or not ?

Comment: I've told you.  Change the server IP.  I sent you that link so you can learn IP subnets.  Understanding it will help you out.  After you change the router IP, you should be able to set your server back.